# Why is downloading a file failing from the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set up a website project in VS2012 and created a folder within the project, `FileStore`. I created an IIS site which points to the project folder.

I have a file saved in the `FileStore` folder which I want to allow the user to download from anywhere within the network.

The structure: `project folder\FileStore\myFile.dat`

I have an ASP.net page in `project folder\` where I have a button to download the `myFile.dat` file:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Download File" OnClick="Button3_Click" Width="146px" Height="26px"  />
```

C#:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Download File Button after SP SSIS Job places it in the MLINT\files\ folder.
    if (File.Exists("FileStore\\myFile.DAT")) {
        Response.ContentType = "data/dat";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myFile.DAT");
        Response.TransmitFile("FileStore\\myFile.DAT");
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "File doesn't exist in the system.";
        lblMessage.CssClass = "fontRed";
    }
}
```

I keep receiving the `File doesn't exist in the system.` message.

How can I resolve the issue.

Comment: You should check your MIME type in your IIS settings. I've seen this happen with unrecognized MIME types.

Comment: It depends.  Is `"FileStore\\myFile.DAT"` a UNC path that is known to the server?

Comment: That's not a UNC path, that's a relative path... relative to the project folder.  A UNC path would start out as "\\\\ServerName\\etc" (four backslashes because the UNC path starts with two backslashes, each of which must be escaped in a C# string that does not begin with @").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map the path to the path used by the web server

```
string actualPath = Server.MapPath("~\\FileStore\\myFile.DAT");
if (File.Exists(actualPath))
```